# Find duplicate fields in database, and update field in row

Tags: mysql, sql

Okay, so I have a table which has 3000 rows. Each row is unique, however some fields are duplicated. 
I want to update the rows with fields that are duplicated. I'm having a hard time putting this into words, so I'm sorry if I'm getting it all wrong.

```
For example, the table looks like this: 

+----+--------+--------+-----------+-------+-------+------+--+
| id |  name  | place  |    day    | time1 | time2 | dupe |  |
+----+--------+--------+-----------+-------+-------+------+--+
|  1 | George | Garden | Sunday    | 12:00 | 13:00 |    0 |  |
|  2 | George | House  | Monday    | 15:00 | 18:00 |    0 |  |
|  3 | David  | School | Wednesday | 15:00 | 18:00 |    0 |  |
|  4 | Stan   | Church | Sunday    | 12:00 | 13:00 |    0 |  |
+----+--------+--------+-----------+-------+-------+------+--+
```

I'd like to run a mysql query that checks the table for duplicate names in the name field, and marks the dupe field as 1 if they are a duplicate.

So the dupe fields in row 1 and 2 should be '1' and the rest should be '0'.

Thank you for any help you might be able to provide! I hope I explained it right.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use EXISTS in a CASE statement:

```
select
  t.*,
  case 
    when exists (
      select 1 from tablename
      where id <> t.id and name = t.name
    ) then 1
    else 0
  end dupe
from tablename t
```

Answer (score 1):

You seem to only care about the `name` field.  So:

```
update t join
       (select name
        from t
        group by name
        having count(*) >= 2
       ) dups
       on t.name = dups.name
    set dups = 1;
```